# Is there a way to take a string from inside a public static void and move it "outside" into a new class into a public static string?

Tags: java

In a small example, I'm trying to take information from the String "helloFromMain" in a file called Main.java and move it "outside" the public static void into a public static string in a different file named data.java.

**IN THE FILE MAIN.JAVA**

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args){
       String helloFromMain = "hello";
   }
}
```

**IN THE FILE DATA.JAVA**

```
public class Data {
    public static String helloFromData = helloFromMain;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Also im relatively new to all this**

Comment: `Data.helloFromData = helloFromMain;` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a public static variable from another class.

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args){
       String helloFromMain = "hello";
       Data.helloFromData = helloFromMain;   
   }
}
```

Also, I've found that it's helpful to set a package for all classes, as it makes it simpler to manage importing and FS structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

Simple way.

IN THE FILE MAIN.JAVA

```
public class Main {
   public static String helloFromMain; //declare a public static string, it will be accessible from outside the class.

   public static void main(String[] args){
       helloFromMain = "hello";
   }
}
```

IN THE FILE DATA.JAVA

```
public class Data {
    public static String helloFromData = Main.helloFromMain;
}
```

But be aware that Main.helloFromMain will be null until you call the main constructor.

Advance way :

IN THE FILE MAIN.JAVA

```
public class Main {
   private static String helloFromMain; //This time the static variable is private, so you can't directly use it from outside

   public static void main(String[] args){
       helloFromMain = "hello";
   }

   //We create a public static method to access the private static variable
   public static String getHelloFromMain(){
       return helloFromMain;
   }
}
```

IN THE FILE DATA.JAVA

```
public class Data {
    //We call our public static method from Main.
    public static String helloFromData = Main.getHelloFromMain();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static method in class Data to set the value of the string. If you do this, you don't need to make the variable in class Data public.

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String helloFromMain = "hello";
       Data.setHelloFromData(helloFromMain);
   }
}

public class Data {
    private static String helloFromData;

    public static void setHelloFromData(String newValue) {
        helloFromData = newValue;
    }
}
```